# Когда следует включать кеширование?

Tags: php, cms, кэширование

Доброго вам времен суток! Продолжаю написание кмс системы, собрал собственное кеширование, о нём и пойдёт речь. Дело в том, что при кешированиии шаблонов и страниц, скрипт тратит 0.006 сек., а при отключённом 0.004 сек. На момент подсчёта по страницам сайта гулял только я. И так понимаю в данном случае кеширование не нужно, т.к. с ним время генерации страницы дольше и соответственно процессорного времени потратится больше, а это плохо.

Вопрос : Есть ли смысл включать такое кеширование, когда одновременно по моему сайту будут гулять, ну хотябы человек 10? Будет ли выигрыш по времени, как вы считаете?

и в добавок к вопросу, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие модули для apache, благодаря которым можно подсчитать затрачиваемое процессорное на выполенние поределённого скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я всегда использую принцип наименьшей динамики генерации страницы... точнее - HTML контента средствами PHP.

Например:
У меня есть страница HTML. На этой странице есть еще куча элементов.
Так вот. При заходе Юзера на сайт, я генерирую JS с параметрами, который по итогу отдаю юзеру и исходя из которого наполняется статическая HTML страница => при получении json-а ajax-ом, который генерируется средствами php я изменяю страницу как мне нужно.

Плюсы:

- Шаблон html страницы я могу кэшировать автоматически в независимости от того, какой результат на ней окажется по итогу.
- Очень быстрое обновление контента.
- минимальная нагрузка на сервер.
- С точки зрение формирования контента так даже проще, чем генерить страницу с помощью PHP.

Минусы:

- Слабый комп может долго педалить на моменте отрисовки элементов с помощью JS.

**========= P.S ===========**

Эмс... таким вопросом даже не задавался. Просто я еще никогда не делал сайт для "общака"..
Обычно это различного рода промышленные проекты, которые должны быть оооочень шустрыми и работать под огромными нагрузками.

Думаю, что сейчас тут же Гугл умеет просматривать страницу с учетом того, что контент генерируется на ней с помощью JS.

Банально - в ВК страницы заполняются тем же образом и при клике по линку не происходит как такового перенаправления, а лишь подгружается контент, вешается якорь для истории, но в самой href ссылка может быть вполне адекватная ( оптимизировано как раз для поисковых систем).

И мы получаем что.... Гугль вполне себе понимает динамический контент, Яндекс тоже.... даже ср..ый tut.by и тот в силах это все скушать.

Думаю, что большинство поисковиков уже давно оптимизировано под таковую архитектуру строения сайтов.

Ибо если я все то, что сказал - ложь, то тогда поисковые системы - это двигатель регресса Web технологий :D

Comment: А как дела обстоят в поисковиками?

Comment: По моему опыту - очень и очень плачевно, если бы не поисковики я бы так давным давно все сайты писал бы...

В свое время даже переписывал сайт реализованный подобным образом

Answer (score 1):

Волшебная статейка о [Кэширование в PHP](http://php.russofile.ru/ru/translate/unsort/chachig_in_php/)

Еще хорошо почитать инфу на тему - *Как оптимизировать SQL запросы с целью уменьшения нагрузки на сервер?*

Comment: Статью ту видел, прочитал. Изучу сейчас про запросы.

Answer (score 1):

По моему опыту, кешировать (в памяти/memcache) имеет смысл только данные из внешних источников (БД, файлы, внешние ресурсы).

Для кеша уже готовых страниц лучше использовать какой-нибудь front-end сервер, например nxinx